# How to store values in session if cookie is disabled in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.1 and developing a web application.
I am storing loged in user name and password in session.since session is stored in cookie, once cookie is disabled I am not able to log in.

is there is any solution in SPRING MVC to store session other then cookie.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use URL rewriting to persist the JSESSIONID in the URL's across requests. You can configure the `ServletContext` to use the [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionTrackingMode.html#URL) tracking mode (instead of `COOKIE`) as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes%28java.util.Set%29).

With Servlet 3.0 you do this:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this configuration in servlet.xml? if yes then please let me know how. Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit. See more [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?tag=servlet-3-0). Just remember to do the URL encode/decode steps as well when you force the session to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in my application (Java EE 6, Spring MVC 3.2.4, Spring Security 3.1.4) JSTL's `<c:url>` tags start adding the `sessionid` value to each URL when cookies get disabled. Spring Security works normally. I did not have to do any configuration to achieve this.